Phone Not Recognised on Android Studio Device list
I removed android studio 4.1.3 and installed android studio Koala today. I was previously able to debug via usb. With the new Koala version I have not been successful.

My device shows up on when scanning for devices but never makes it to the device list so I can run my app.
When I unplug and plug my device in the usb port it shows up as 4 devices and I am not sure if this is related to my problem.

here is a screen shot showing adb devices and the IDE showing "No Devices"


Please edit your question and include the output of the command adb devices. BTW the device manager screenshot is easier to interpret if you select one of the devices that belong to your phone and then changein menu view to "devices by connection". That way all devices from your phone end up in the same subtree.

After many days of back and forth installations between 4.1.3 and koala, I simply downgraded the build tools that are installed with Koala and everything works fine now.
